# rspec feature and model spec not passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

The following are 2 specs are wrote for signing in a user into an account:

```
it "signs user in with valid email/password combination" do 
    user = User.create!(user_attributes)

    visit root_url
    click_link "Sign In"

    fill_in "Email", with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password

    click_link "Sign In"

    expect(current_path).to eq(user_path(user))
    expect(page).to have_text("Welcome back, #{user.first_name}!")

    expect(page).to have_link(user.name)
    expect(page).not_to have_link('Sign In')
    expect(page).not_to have_link('Sign Up')
end

it "does not sign in invalid email/password combo" do 
    user = User.create!(user_attributes)

    visit root_url

    click_link "Sign In"

    fill_in "Email", with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: "no match"

    click_link "Sign In"

    expect(page).to have_text("Invalid email/password combination!")

    expect(page).not_to have_link(user.name)
    expect(page).to have_link('Sign In')
    expect(page).to have_link('Sign Up')
end
```

And i'm getting the following error messages that i cant resolve:

```
    1) signing a user in signs user in with valid email/password combination
     Failure/Error: expect(current_path).to eq(user_path(user))

       expected: "/users/1"
            got: "/session/new"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/features/sign_in_spec.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) signing a user in does not sign in invalid email/password combo
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_text("Invalid email/password combination!")
       expected to find text "Invalid email/password combination!" in "The Market Sign Up | Sign In | Home About Products Location Register Log In Sign In Email Password www.themarket.com | 312-401-4570 | Beverly | Oak Lawn | Evergreen Park"
     # ./spec/features/sign_in_spec.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is my session controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new 

end

def create 
    if user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id 
        flash[:notice] = "Welcome back, #{user.first_name}!"
        redirect_to user
    else 
        flash.now[:alert] = "Invalid email/password combination!"
        render :new
    end
end
```

end

When I run it in the browser it works just fine but the test is failing and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `click_link "Sign In"` instead of submitting the form.

```
visit root_url
click_link "Sign In"
fill_in "Email", with: user.email
fill_in "Password", with: user.password
click_button "Sign In"
```

You can clean the spec up to read:

```
let!(:user){ User.create!(user_attributes) }

def sign_in_with(email, password)
  visit root_url
  click_link "Sign In"
  fill_in "Email", with: email
  fill_in "Password", with: password
  click_button "Sign In"
end

# prefer scenario over it for feature specs
it "signs user in with valid email/password combination" do 
    sign_in_with(user.email, user.password)
    expect(current_path).to eq(user_path(user))
    expect(page).to have_text("Welcome back, #{user.first_name}!")
    expect(page).to have_link(user.name)
    expect(page).not_to have_link('Sign In')
    expect(page).not_to have_link('Sign Up')
end

it  "does not sign in invalid email/password combo" do 
    sign_in_with(user.email, "no match")
    expect(page).to have_text("Invalid email/password combination!")
    expect(page).not_to have_link(user.name)
    expect(page).to have_link('Sign In')
    expect(page).to have_link('Sign Up')
end
```

Comment: Thanks!.  I didn't realize that click_button submits a form. Very helpful!

Comment: Usually using `click_link` instead of `click_button` raises an error as Capybara can not find the element. In this case you happened to have a link with the exact same text which masked the error.